# Asking forgiveness from a deceased person who has no gravesite

Tags: death, repentance-teshuvah, cemetery-grave

The **Rambam** in [Hilchos Teshuvah 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.2.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> **הַחוֹטֵא לַחֲבֵרוֹ וּמֵת חֲבֵרוֹ קֹדֶם שֶׁיְּבַקֵּשׁ מְחִילָה מֵבִיא עֲשָׂרָה בְּנֵי אָדָם וּמַעֲמִידָן עַל קִבְרוֹ** וְיֹאמַר בִּפְנֵיהֶם חָטָאתִי לַה' אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְלִפְלוֹנִי זֶה שֶׁכָּךְ וְכָךְ עָשִׂיתִי לוֹ.
>
> **One who committed a sin against his friend, and the friend died before he asked his forgiveness, should bring ten adults at his grave** and there say: "I have sinned against the Lord God of Israel and against this person, and I have done against him such and such."

However, in a scenario where the deceased person has no grave--   ex: if a non-observant person was cremated, or the person's body was never recovered etc-- **what should/can be done instead**?

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes there is nothing one can do.